# how to implement zoom and pinch zoom effect in application?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one photo application in which i want to implement zoom and pinch zoom effect same as default photo application in iphone.How it possible please help me for this query.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The UIScrollView component takes care of functionality like that. 
Try starting out here :[UIScrollView Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

The ScrollViewSuite (link in the reference) has a example that you can use.